# Laravel - Request error on server

Tags: php, sql, apache, laravel

I'm trying get a Laravel project on a server ; everything work fine on local, I sent all the files to the server, changed routes.php and .env so that everything could work ( database, query, routes... ).

I work behind a reverse proxy, but it's not a problem to get the routes to work.

I can log in, but I cannot access or execute whatever that uses the Database (except log in).

**Example :**

*Controller :*

```
public function show($id) {
   $compte = Compte::find($id);
   $suiviFormation = User_formation::join('formation', 'formation.id_formation', '=', 'user_formation.id_formation')
                                            ->join('type_formation', 'formation.id_type_formation', '=', 'type_formation.id_type_formation')
                                            ->where('id_compte', $id)
                                            ->where(function($query){
                                                $query->where('formation.id_organisme', 1)
                                                        ->orWhere('formation.id_organisme', Auth::user()->id_organisme);
                                            })
                                            ->where('valide', 1)
                                            ->orderBy('type_formation.nom',  'asc')
                                            ->orderBy('formation.nom',  'asc')
                                            ->orderBy('date_formation',  'desc')
                                            ->get();
        $formations = array();
        $types = array();

        foreach($suiviFormation as $suivi){
            $formations[] = Formation::find($suivi->id_formation);
        }

        foreach($formations as $formation){
            $types[$formation->id_type_formation] = $formation->type_formation->nom;
        }   


        $userPoste = User_Poste::where('id_compte', $id)
            ->where('date_fin', null)
            ->first();


        $formationsAvailable = Formation::select('formation.id_type_formation', 'formation.nom', 'formation_importance.importance')
                                            ->join('formation_importance', 'formation_importance.id_formation', '=', 'formation.id_formation')
                                            ->join('poste', 'poste.id_poste', '=', 'formation_importance.id_poste')
                                            ->where('formation_importance.id_poste', $userPoste->id_poste)
                                            ->where('importance', '!=', 1)
                                            ->orderBy('formation.nom', 'asc')
                                            ->groupBy('formation.id_formation')
                                            ->get();

        return view('formation/formation_show', ['compte' => $compte, 'types' => $types, 'suiviFormation' => $suiviFormation,
            'formations' => $formations, 'formationsAvailable' => $formationsAvailable]);
    }
```

*The error :*

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 624: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 
1146 Table 'greement.Formation' doesn't exist 
(SQL: select * from `Formation` where `Formation`.`id_formation` = 61 limit 1)
```

Every single error look like this one.

---

Knowing that a part of the connexion to the database is working, how can other pages don't work ?

.env :

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY= appkey
DB_HOST= database.host
DB_DATABASE=greement
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=*******
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

EDIT : I don't have direct access to the server, I can only use FTP & phpMyAdmin for the database.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have tables in DB on your server. You need to run migrations with `php artisan migrate` command which will create tables for you. Or you can restore DB data on a server from a DB dump file.

Comment: I don't have access to the server directly so I can't perform this. I'll try with restoring the DB (added in question). Thanks

Comment: Restore the DB date from a .sql file didn't solve the problem, I'm still having the same error. Plus, I do have tables in the DB, because I couldn't log into the website if I didn't.

Comment: You want to tell me you have `Formation` table but still getting exactly the same error? If not, check with phpMyAdmin if table name is exactly the same Laravel is trying to use.

Comment: On the local DB, I have `formation`, which works well.
On the server DB, I did have the same table, I renamed it to `Formation` to try if it changed something. 
I do have know `Table 'greement.User_qual_ops' doesn't exist` as an error.

I just realize while writting this comment the error has changed. I'm going to try to rename all the tables.
I just wonder why it need this change on the server as it doesn't care on the local DB.